# Timex - Getting the timezone information from DateTime

Tags: timex

I am looking for a way to get the timezone information back from a date time.

```
iex(13)> t = Timex.now("America/Los_Angeles")
#<DateTime(2016-10-23T12:45:34.697369-07:00 America/Los_Angeles)>
iex(14)> Timex.<given_t_return_timezone>??
```

Given `t`, I want back `"America/Los_Angeles"` again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I knew it had to be easy. Rather than looking at `Timex` for this, we can simply do:

```
t.time_zone
```

This is part of Elixir itself since `t` is a `DateTime`.